# Stop auto refresh when page is out of focus and minimized on win and mac for all browsers

Tags: javascript, refresh

I have a scenario where i want to stop auto refresh of page in the following cases:

1. It is out of focus
2. Browser is minimized.

I am able to do first but especially on mac I'm unable to figure out the way.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by auto refresh of page?

Comment: I have a function written which gets called after every 1 min, i want to make sure that function only makes ajax call when page is in focus

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you tried, but if you want to find browser window inactive state you can use the [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/) which allows us to detect when a page is hidden to the user.

**NOTE: (from w3.org)**

> This specification defines a means for site developers to
>   programmatically determine the current visibility state of the page in
>   order to develop power and CPU efficient web applications.

You have to register for `visibilitychange` event, the sample code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var timer = 0;
   var PERIOD_VISIBLE = 1000;
   var PERIOD_NOT_VISIBLE = 60000;

   function onLoad() {
       timer = setInterval(checkEmail, (document.hidden) ? PERIOD_NOT_VISIBLE : PERIOD_VISIBLE);
       if(document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", visibilityChanged);
   }

   function visibilityChanged() {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer = setInterval(checkEmail, (document.hidden) ? PERIOD_NOT_VISIBLE : PERIOD_VISIBLE);
   }

   function checkEmail() { 
       // Check server for new messages
   }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="onLoad()">
 </body>
</html>
```

**Check already answered Stack overflow question for Reference:**

[Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)